# Eclipse JSP editor validation message

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, jsp

The JSP editor in Eclipse Mars is giving me a 'validation message' but the code works fine. 
The following is a snippet from my navigation.jsp.

```
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.contextPath}" />
```

Using the baseURL as follows:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="${baseURL}/"
            style="text-decoration: none;">ABCD</a>
```

The reference in the HREF ${baseURL} is producing a validation message. I tried turning off all JSP validation in preferences as suggested everywhere, but I still get the warning. Is there a way to circumvent the problem. Thanks for any assistance.

The error I get is 
src/main/webapp/resources/js/fragment/${baseURL} not found.

I have come to the conclusion that this error is specific to the project. I created an eclipse static web project and converted it to a Maven project. Created a folder structure like my original project and put the following code in it called x.jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="baseURL"
value="${req.scheme}://${req.serverName}:${req.serverPort}${req.contextPath}" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="${baseURL}"
            style="text-decoration: none;">EDVS</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This test code did not create any error in the new project. I moved this code, x.jsp to my original project and and error is produced saying that src/man/webapp/resources/js/fragment/${baseURL} could not be found. When a file produces an error in one project and not another I surmise that the problem is project specific. I have compared a number of properties between the two projects but cannot see the cause of the error. The original project is much older and has a lot more files in it so may be something I did in the past is causing this validation error.

Comment: What _is_ the validation message? What is it telling you?

Comment: As stated in the edited version, the message returned is "The error I get is src/main/webapp/resources/js/fragment/${baseURL} not found.".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you, intentionally or not, have https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources installed, and its validator (which isn't the *JSP Validator* itself) enabled on the project that's showing an error. Check the list of Validators on the project's **Validators** property page.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I checked both projects "Validation" and neither have 'Enable project specific settings'. This would imply to me that both projects are validating the same way. My feeling is something happened to the bad project control files. I am thinking of making a new project and copy the old files to this new one and see what happens.